# How to convert arrayBuffer into an mp3 audio?

Tags: javascript, audio

with using AudioContext of javascript the mixing of audio is achived and for exporting the audio mix i used OfflineAudioContext and,n, lame js to encode the decoded audio , now the expoort is working fine but it is very slow , i am looking for an efficient way to do that with more faster than the current one .

Comment: There is no better cross-browser way at present to do this. You might consider using OGG instead ([Firefox can record to OGG natively](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/AudioVideo-on-Firefox.html), Chrome you will need [a JS OGG Encoder](https://github.com/astroza/chrome_ogg_encoder)). The fastest way to encode MP3 is using [PNACL](http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient/pnacl/introduction-to-portable-native-client) and the [NACLPorts Lame](https://github.com/anvio/naclports/tree/master/libraries/lame-3.99-5) but it's Chrome-only and non-trivial!

Comment: Didn't test it myself, but according to the LameJS project, it supposed to run "20 times faster than realtime". Looking over the code it seems to utilize JavaScript's `Float32Array`. I would check if your browser supports that technology, and also if it supports WebGL for GPU based matrix multiplication (it probably does). If it doesn't, I'll try with a browser that does and check the speed then.

Comment: You could look into using emscripten and compiling the lame encoder source.  No clue how that would work out for you and it might be more difficult than it's worth to you.

Comment: @Goblinlord  I tried with lame js to process the arraybuffer , Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-lame

The above is the lame encoder which does the encoding process of your pcm data.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [thread][1]

```js
  document.querySelector('input').onchange = function(){
      var fileReader  = new FileReader;
      fileReader.onload = function(){
         var arrayBuffer = this.result;
         snippet.log(arrayBuffer);
         snippet.log(arrayBuffer.byteLength);
         }
      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0]);

      var url = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]); 
      audio_player.src = url; 
      audio_player.play();
    };
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<input id="audio_file" type="file" accept="audio/*" />
<audio id="audio_player" />
```

Comment: How does your answer help with the question ?